# Failed deployment with Heroku (npm java)

Tags: java, node.js, npm

I am trying to deploy my app through Heroku, which is working perfectly on localhost. Even though I had some troubles installing java module on localhost, I finally did it, thanks to this post: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/10289.

Now, I'm getting apparently the same error deploying the app on Heroku, but now I'm not able to fix it. I set even the Java Buildpack, just in case, but it didnt help.

I hope someone could help me!

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "tachology",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "server/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.6.0",
    "angular-animate": "~1.6.0",
    "angular-aria": "~1.6.0",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.6.0",
    "angular-resource": "~1.6.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.6.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.4.2",
    "angular-validation-match": "^1.9.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.7.2",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.6.1",
    "bluebird": "^3.3.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.13.3",
    "cal-heatmap": "^3.6.2",
    "composable-middleware": "^0.3.0",
    "connect-mongo": "^1.2.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.3.5",
    "core-js": "^2.2.1",
    "errorhandler": "^1.4.2",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "express-jwt": "^5.0.0",
    "express-session": "^1.11.3",
    "fast-json-patch": "^1.0.0",
    "font-awesome": ">=4.1.0",
    "gridfs": "^1.0.0",
    "java": "^0.8.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jsonformatter": "^0.6.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.6.1",
    "lusca": "^1.3.0",
    "method-override": "^2.3.5",
    "mongoose": "^4.1.2",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "multer-gridfs-storage": "^1.2.2",
    "ng-google-charts": "^0.1.3",
    "passport": "~0.3.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pug": "2.0.0-beta4",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.0",
    "shrink-ray": "^0.1.3",
    "sprint-js": "~0.1.0",
    "uikit": "^3.0.0-beta.24"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.6.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.6.5",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.0.4",
    "babel-register": "^6.6.5",
    "browser-sync": "^2.8.0",
    "bs-fullscreen-message": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "eslint": "^2.12.0",
    "del": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp-env": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-eslint": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-inject": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-istanbul": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-istanbul-enforcer": "^1.0.3",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "gulp-mocha": "^2.1.3",
    "gulp-node-inspector": "^0.1.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-protractor": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-rev": "^7.0.0",
    "gulp-rev-replace": "^0.4.2",
    "gulp-sort": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.2",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.5",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.5",
    "gulp-stylint": "^3.0.0",
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-build-control": "^0.7.0",
    "isparta": "^4.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.3.7",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.0",
    "lazypipe": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.5.1",
    "webpack-stream": "^3.2.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.16.0",
    "html-webpack-harddisk-plugin": "~0.0.2",
    "pug-html-loader": "^1.0.8",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "0.17.0",
    "ng-annotate-loader": "~0.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.24.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "isparta-instrumenter-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "isparta-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "through2": "^2.0.1",
    "open": "~0.0.4",
    "istanbul": "1.1.0-alpha.1",
    "chai": "^3.2.0",
    "sinon": "^1.16.1",
    "chai-as-promised": "^5.1.0",
    "chai-things": "^0.2.0",
    "karma": "~0.13.3",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-script-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~1.0.0",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "~0.0.20",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "~0.3.7",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.8.0",
    "mocha": "^3.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.4.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.4",
    "proxyquire": "^1.0.1",
    "strip-ansi": "^3.0.1",
    "supertest": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.2.2",
    "npm": "3.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "gulp test",
    "update-webdriver": "node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update",
    "start": "node server"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And this is the logs when deploying:

```
Warning: remote: Compressing source files... done.        
remote: Building source:        
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected        
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment        
remote:                
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true        
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false        
remote:        NODE_ENV=production        
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true        
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries        
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  6.2.2        
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   3.9.5        
remote:                
remote:        Resolving node version 6.2.2...        
remote:        Downloading and installing node 6.2.2...        
remote:        npm 3.9.5 already installed with node        
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache        
remote:        Skipping cache restore (new-signature)        
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies        
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)        
remote:                
remote:        > iltorb@1.3.6 install /tmp/build_2beaa787f71f40bc41e528a14b9c399c/node_modules/iltorb        
remote:        > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build        
remote:                
remote:        [iltorb] Success: "/tmp/build_2beaa787f71f40bc41e528a14b9c399c/node_modules/iltorb/build/bindings/iltorb.node" is installed via remote        
remote:                
remote:        > node-zopfli@1.4.0 install /tmp/build_2beaa787f71f40bc41e528a14b9c399c/node_modules/node-zopfli        
remote:        > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build        
remote:                
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://node-zopfli.s3.amazonaws.com/Release/zopfli-v1.4.0-node-v48-linux-x64.tar.gz        
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for node-zopfli@1.4.0 and node@6.2.2 (node-v48 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)        
remote:        make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_2beaa787f71f40bc41e528a14b9c399c/node_modules/node-zopfli/build'        
remote:        CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/src/zopfli-binding.o        
remote:        CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/src/png/zopflipng.o        
remote:        CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/blocksplitter.o        
remote:        CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/cache.o        
remote:        CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/deflate.o        
remote:        CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/gzip_container.o        
remote:        CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/hash.o        
remote:        CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/katajainen.o        
remote:        CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/lz77.o        
remote:        CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/squeeze.o        
remote:        CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/tree.o        
remote:        CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/util.o        
remote:        CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/zlib_container.o        
remote:        CC(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopfli/zopfli_lib.o        
remote:        CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopflipng/zopflipng_lib.o        
remote:        CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopflipng/lodepng/lodepng.o        
remote:        CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli/zopfli/src/zopflipng/lodepng/lodepng_util.o        
remote:        SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/zopfli.node        
remote:        COPY Release/zopfli.node        
remote:        COPY /tmp/build_2beaa787f71f40bc41e528a14b9c399c/node_modules/node-zopfli/lib/binding/node-v48-linux-x64/zopfli.node        
remote:        TOUCH Release/obj.target/action_after_build.stamp        
remote:        make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_2beaa787f71f40bc41e528a14b9c399c/node_modules/node-zopfli/build'        
remote:                
remote:        > java@0.8.0 install /tmp/build_2beaa787f71f40bc41e528a14b9c399c/node_modules/java        
remote:        > node-gyp rebuild        
remote:                
remote:        [node-java] Error: not found: javac        
remote:        gyp: Call to 'node findJavaHome.js' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp        
remote:        gyp ERR! configure error        
remote:        gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1        
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/tmp/build_2beaa787f71f40bc41e528a14b9c399c/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:305:16)        
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)        
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)        
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:204:12)        
remote:        gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-128-generic        
remote:        gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_2beaa787f71f40bc41e528a14b9c399c/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_2beaa787f71f40bc41e528a14b9c399c/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"        
remote:        gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_2beaa787f71f40bc41e528a14b9c399c/node_modules/java        
remote:        gyp ERR! node -v v6.2.2        
remote:        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1        
remote:        gyp ERR! not ok        
remote:        tachology@0.0.0 /tmp/build_2beaa787f71f40bc41e528a14b9c399c        
remote:        ├── angular@1.6.6        
remote:        ...      
remote:        ├── sprint-js@0.1.0        
remote:        └── uikit@3.0.0-beta.30        
remote:                
remote:        npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-128-generic        
remote:        npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_2beaa787f71f40bc41e528a14b9c399c/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_2beaa787f71f40bc41e528a14b9c399c/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "install" "--unsafe-perm" "--userconfig" "/tmp/build_2beaa787f71f40bc41e528a14b9c399c/.npmrc"        
remote:        npm ERR! node v6.2.2        
remote:        npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5        
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE        
remote:                
remote:        npm ERR! java@0.8.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`        
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1        
remote:        npm ERR!        
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the java@0.8.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.        
remote:        npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.        
remote:        npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the java package,        
remote:        npm ERR! not with npm itself.        
remote:        npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:        
remote:        npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild        
remote:        npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:        
remote:        npm ERR!     npm bugs java        
remote:        npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:        
remote:        npm ERR!     npm owner ls java        
remote:        npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.        
remote:                
remote:        npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:        
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/build_2beaa787f71f40bc41e528a14b9c399c/npm-debug.log        
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed        
remote:                
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:        
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys        
remote:                
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:        
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/        
remote:                
remote:        Love,        
remote:        Heroku        
remote:                
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.        
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed        
remote: Verifying deploy....        
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to tachology.        
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/tachology.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/tachology.git'
 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your node-gyp requires java to be built correctly. The thing with Heroku's architecture is that it only provides you what you specify/need. Right now I don't think Heroku understands that it needs a JVM to run your application. So you should provide a buildpack. A build pack put very simply is a set of rules telling Heroku what to set-up, install and build. There is a buildpack for JVM called `heroku/jvm`.
So, what you have to do is add this to your application through the dashboard or your CLI via `heroku buildpacks:add heroku/jvm`.

There is one more thing to do. Since your app requires javac at build time itself, we should pull up the build order for java/jvm . So in that case you should probably do `heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/jvm`. This puts the JVM buildpack at position 1 and pushes every other buildpack down the order.

Now when the app starts building, it first sets up the JVM (thus enabling javac for your instance) and then runs the NodeJS build. This build will now pick up the javac from the current instance and build accordingly.

Ref: [Mulitple Buildpacks in Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app)